# Handle routes to static pages while converting to SPA

Tags: javascript, apache, polymer

I am tasked with updating a Microsoft Frontpage website and I am going to use Polymer with the Polymer Starter Kit. In that it uses a javascript router to handle pages. Now it will be hosted on an apache server and I know how to setup apache to route everything to my index.html file to get the router to do my routing, but I am looking for a way to also route to existing static pages as I work on the conversion of this website so I can release pages as I go and users can still access the old pages that I haven't converted yet.

Is there an easy way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Can u not just prepend equivalent of # to your map of static routes?  This would qualify non-polimer routing to be brought in scope with polymer routes.

Comment: I'm not sure I will try. I don't really do front-end development I mostly just work on the backends and services so this is new to me.

Comment: https://github.com/erikringsmuth/polymer-router-demos  good reading there

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thanks and sorry I didn't rtfm. In my head I thought I was going to have to do some .htaccess rules to route certain requests and instead of reading I was like there has to be a better way and surely someone knows.

Comment: The polymer starter kit uses pages.js and it automatically redirects routes it doesn't match.